# MongoDB store value in a variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I am using vscode extension of mongodb. I am trying to store the value in a variable and it returns undefined. The query works fine.

```
var obj = db.categories.find({_id : "Space Opera"}, {_id : 0, parent : 1})  // undefined
```

--- Edit ---

categories is a document representing a graph data structure

```
db.categories.insertMany([
  {
    _id: "Space Opera",
    ancestors: ["Science Fiction", "Fiction", "Science Fiction & Fantasy"],
    parent: ["Science Fiction"],
  },
  {
    _id: "Dystopian",
    ancestors: ["Science Fiction", "Fiction", "Science Fiction & Fantasy"],
    parent: ["Science Fiction"],
  },
  {
    _id: "Cyberpunk",
    ancestors: ["Science Fiction", "Fiction", "Science Fiction & Fantasy"],
    parent: ["Science Fiction"],
  },
  {
    _id: "Science Fiction",
    ancestors: ["Fiction", "Science Fiction & Fantasy"],
    parent: ["Fiction", "Science Fiction & Fantasy"],
  },
  {
    _id: "Fantasy",
    ancestors: ["Science Fiction & Fantasy"],
    parent: ["Science Fiction & Fantasy"],
  },
  {
    _id: "Science Fiction & Fantasy",
    ancestors: [],
    parent: [],
  },
  {
    _id: "Fiction",
    ancestors: [],
    parent: [],
  },
]);
```

Books collection object example below:

```
{
    ISBN: "0006",
    title: "Book6",
    pages: NumberInt("135"),
    price: NumberDecimal("170.5"),
    copies: NumberInt("10"),
    language: "russian",
    author: ["Author1", "Author2", "Author3"],
    category: ["Science Fiction & Fantasy"],
    genre: ["Genre-6", "Genre-0"],
    character: ["Character-4", "Character-3"],
  }
```

I want to store a variable like this:

```
var category = ["Space Opera"]
```

---  Another side question ---

Since it is a graph data structure and the "Science Fiction" category has 2 parents I want to perform the following operation.

- Retire Science Fiction and assign all books to the parent category

I have the following code that works for books that have a single category and the category has only one parent. Does not work for science fiction, I believe I need some conditionals checking whether the category has more than one parents and dependent on which category I want, update the category.

```
db.books.aggregate([
   { $match: { category: "Space Opera" } },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "categories",
            pipeline: [
               { $match: { _id: "Space Opera" } },
               { $project: { _id: 0, parent: { $first: "$parent" } } }
            ],
            as: "category"
         }
   },
   { $set: { category: { $first: "$category.parent" } } }
]).toArray().forEach(function (doc) {
   db.books.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { category: [doc.category] } });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the property "_id" in mongodb is a sensitive issue... :) , this is where the database stores the IDs of documents . Contrary to a normal relational db these IDs are not incrimental integers but Object Ids created by mongodb itself . So this query returns undefined because "Space Opera" couldnt have been an Object Id in the first place nor 0 could. I would be glad to help more , if you provided a little bit more of your code .

Comment: I have added some additional info.